# What to use instead of Sequelize findAll when getting current user?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have an express API, what can I use instead of findAll? I want to query the current user that's logged in with all its information belonging to that user using sequelize belongsTo?

```
var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router()
const db = require('../database/db.js');
const User = db.Users;



// get all users
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
    User.findAll()
      .then(Users => {
          res.json(Users)
      })
      .catch(err => {
          res.send('error: ' + err)
      })
})


module.exports = router
```

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#-find-search-for-one-specific-element-in-the-database

Comment: You can create middleware for authenticating the current user via token(Depends on your code) and adding the current user details in the body as a new parameter. Let me know if you need a working code example.

Comment: Yeah, that would be great. I would really appreciate that

Comment: How are you authenticating your user?

Comment: through auth0 custom database feature. So I create a user with auth0 (email, password) those user details get added to my database and It creates a user_id along with the details the user added.

Comment: Sorry, Somehow I missed the notification please check - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54921318/app-use-inside-a-promise-bookshelf-js-express-basic-auth/54923286#54923286